# How does curvature of our eye affect our perception of the world?

Tags: optics, curvature, vision, perception

The front part of the eye which can allow light to enter is a bit curved, so shouldn't this cause us to see a curved distorted version of reality when it is really not there? Is there any way to quantify this?

If the question is not clear,  suppose we stereographically project a plane onto a spherical surface, then clearly, what is straight on the plane is no longer straight on the sphere.. hence my doubt.

Comment: I submit that this question, while phrased in physics terms, needs to be addressed in terms of cognitive psychology. Visual information input is highly processed. The brain's visual system is geared to constructing a self-consistent interpretation of the incoming information, including consistency with tactile sensations. We know that boxes stack well. When we recognize something as functioning as a stackable a box we assume all the edges are straight and the angles are right angles. That informs our interpretation. I propose to migrate this question to a stackexchange site for Neuroscience

Comment: I am really not sure what to make of your comment. I understand where you're coming from, but I really don't think cog sci people would be able to answer this. I'll wait a day or two and repost based on communities reception

Comment: Corneal curvature results in most of the focusing power of the eye, with the lens of the eye doing the fine tuning.  Also, the image on the retina is inverted and focused on a very curved surface, a lot of image processing is done on the retina, and the final interpretation of the image is done in the brain.  Whether you interpret the world as "curved" or not is strongly dependent on that interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding simple optics, we should see the world around us even overhead, as the lense is producing an image at the backside of our eyes which is overhead.

Moreover, the information from the right eye is projected to the left hemisphere of the brain and vice versa (crossing of the opric radiation).

All in all, a little bit of curvature seems not to be our biggest problem if we were taking seriously what comes directly to the brain from the eyes.

To be serious, the visual impression of the outside world is made within our brain, and it is **learned**. Therefore, I suppose that the brain compensates this curvature as it compensates the overhead projection.

Comment: For a good example of how vision is learned, see [Upside down glasses](http://www.madsci.org/posts/archives/mar97/858984531.Ns.r.html)